# Problems with some links

Tags: support, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

I have a problem with some links

There is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563959/6110094

Thee third link does not matter if I just have it in the text or it done via the hyperlink button does not appear as a link only as the normal text.

Any suggestions how to sort it out?

Comment: I've edited post for you by adding the missing space.

Comment: A so the space was the problem

Comment: Since the migration to CommonMark, related: [URL after colon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349717/commonmark-link-rendering-differently-on-client-and-server-sides)